# Why I get no identifier for declarator ....?

Tags: d

Why I get no identifier for declarator .... ?

`mixin` are useless in this case but that is a minimal example of my problem.

`tl`var is type of `TL` so i do not see where is the problem.

Code also on [dpaste](http://dpaste.dzfl.pl/6349e1fc7a90), same error with dmd or ldc.

Thanks for your help

```
import std.stdio;
import std.typecons;

struct Data{
    int x;
    int y;
}

template getcode(T)
{
    mixin(`
          alias TL = Tuple!(
                            int,"x",
                            int,"y"
                           );
          `);
    TL tl;
    mixin(`
          tl.x = 10;
          tl.y = 5;
          `);
}

void main()
{

    getcode!Data;
    writeln( tl.x );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that templates can only contain declarations, not statements or expressions. This is the offending code:

```
mixin(`
      tl.x = 10;
      tl.y = 5;
      `);
```

These are assignments, not declarations. This is why you get the weird error message "Error: no identifier for declarator tl.x". The compiler thinks you are trying to make a declaration of a variable, and it can't find the type "tl.x"... or something like that. The solution is to set the value of the tuple inline, like so:

```
template getcode(T)
{
    mixin(`alias TL = Tuple!(int, "x", int, "y");`);
    TL tl = TL(10, 5);
}
```

Or, to better match your original code:

```
template getcode(T)
{
    mixin(`alias TL = Tuple!(int, "x", int, "y");`);
    TL tl = mixin(`TL(10, 5)`);
}
```

There is now another problem. In main, where you instantiate the template, you will get the error "Error: getcode!(Data) has no effect". This is because a template instantiation on its own is not a declaration. You have to either alias it to a symbol, or mix it in using a mixin statement.

Aliasing it to a symbol will allow you to access the declarations inside the template through that symbol, and mixing it in puts the template's declarations into the scope it's instantiated in. I would recommend the first option, as it's more hygenic. You shouldn't use `mixin` unless you absolutely have to.

```
void main()
{
    //Error: getcode!(Data) has no effect
    //getcode!Data;

    //Ok
    //mixin getcode!Data;
    //writeln( tl.x );

    //Ok
    alias Code = getcode!Data;
    writeln( Code.tl.x );
}
```

You can see my corrected version of your code here:

http://dpaste.dzfl.pl/f6152a35bfc8